# "too many redirects" with SSL redirect of CakePHP on heroku

Tags: cakephp, redirect, ssl, heroku

I'm getting `[310] Too many redirects` errors on heroku, when my cake app tries to redirect to a secure connection after forcing it with `SecurityComponent::requireSecure()`.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = '_blackholeCallback';
    $this->Security->requireSecure('login', 'register');
}

// ...

public function _blackholeCallback($type) {
    if ($type == 'secure') {
        $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that CakePHP and heroku handle their secure connections differently.

Cake's checking for the environmental variable 'HTTPS' to be true or false.
heroku doesn't provide this env, instead they're sending the header 'X-Forwarded-Proto' with a 'https' value.

You have to add a new (or overwrite the old 'ssl') detector and check for this header.
I did it like this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->request->addDetector('ssl', array('callback' => function() {
            return CakeRequest::header('X-Forwarded-Proto') == 'https';
        }));

    // ...

    }
}
```

Hope i could help everyone who's having this issue after me. it got me several hours to figure this out.

Comment: Nice find! Maybe you should consider creating a 'patch' for this and create a 'pull' request on GitHub. Don't know if this will interfere with 'regular' SSL hosting situations, but as far I can tell this shouldn't cause problems?

Comment: Yeah, I was already thinking to do that, too. AFAIK "X-Forwarded-Proto" Header is a de facto standard. Should not cause problems. Just have to search for some sources, so the guys believe me.

Comment: Thanks in advance, although I'm not using heroku myself, improving CakePHP is always good :)